# regex - match exactly to a string portion in awk

Tags: regex, awk

I have a file where one column contains strings that are composed of characters separated by ,
example:

```
a123456, a54321, a12312
```

I need to find lines that contain a specific number in the comma separated list.
example: I want to find all lines that contain only `a12345`.

I tried to use the following:

```
awk ' $1~/a12345/ {print}'
```

but this prints out the line containing:

```
a123456, a54321, a12312
```

because the regex is matching the first 6 characters in `a123456`, I guess.

My question is, how can I make an regex that will only print out the lines that contain only an exact match?

Comment: Only in the first or in any field?

Comment: `$1~/a12345,/ {print}`? Or could there be a situation where there is only 1 field?

Comment: This seems to more complicated. If I do awk ' $1~/a12312/ {print}' the line a123456, a54321, a12312  does not print.

Comment: A situation with only one field, i.e. no commas, would not occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using word match of grep like below:

```
grep -w a123456 myfile.txt
```

if you need in field that just starts, then use something like:

```
egrep -w ^a123456 myfile.txt
```

Comment: Using grep seems to work perfectly for this situation. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '/(^|[^[:alnum:]])a12345([^[:alnum:]]|$)/' file
$ awk '/(^|[^[:alnum:]])a123456([^[:alnum:]]|$)/' file
a123456, a54321, a12312
```

With GNU awk you could use word-delimiters:

```
$ awk '/\<a12345\>/' file
$ awk '/\<a123456\>/' file
a123456, a54321, a12312
```

Answer (score 0):

With awk:

```
awk -F ',\\s*' '$1 == "a12345"' filename
```

To split the line along commas (optionally followed by whitespace) and select only those lines whose first field is exactly "a12345". This will work even if the field contains characters after "a12345" that count as a word boundary, which is to say that

```
a12345.foo, bar, baz
```

is filtered out.

If more than a single field is to be tested, then you'll have to test all fields:

```
awk -F ',\\s*' 'function check() { for(i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) { if($i == "a12345") return 1; } return 0 } check()' filename
```

Comment: You should mention that the `\s` makes it gawk-specific.

Comment: mawk accepts it too, actually. I'll go check what POSIX says, hold on.

Comment: Yeah I usually forget that mawk has some of the "gawk-specific" features now. Not sure what the right term is to use for something that's non-POSIX, was developed for gawk and now may or may not also be in mawk (I don't have mawk, nor am I particularly interested in getting it)! I'll probably stick with gawk-specific and keep being corrected :-). See http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#GNU-Regexp-Operators for the "gawk-specific" operators.

Comment: Hmm...POSIX says awk should allow EREs as `FS`, which don't include `\s` but would include `[[:space:]]`. In practice, however, only gawk accepts `-F ',[[:space:]]*`, so the non-POSIX `\\s` is ironically more portable. Well, if OP really has problems with it, `-F ',[ \t]*'` should cover all likely cases.

Comment: I don't think mawk claims to be POSIX does it? I thought it was just a minimally featured awk optimized for speed of execution. /usr/xpg4/bin/awk on Solaris (which does claim to be POSIX) does accept `-F',[[:space:]]*'` but, as expected, not `-F',\\s*`. `nawk`, also as expected, accepts neither, but then it never claimed to be POSIX.

Comment: mawk claims conformance to POSIX 1003.2 (or so it says [here](http://invisible-island.net/mawk/manpage/mawk.txt)), so I think this is a bug.

Comment: Yeah, it if claims to be POSIX and doesn't support character classes in it's EREs then that is a bug. Just curious: Is it just in field separators or all EREs that it fails to recognize character classes?

Comment: All, at least the version I have here. That appears to be a very old version, though; if I piece it together correctly, mawk development halted a long time ago until Thomas Dickey picked it up in 2009 and added features like this. His version of mawk supports all this, apparently, but it is not distributed by everybody™.